# Puzzle with Many Slashes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

My professor gave us this puzzle and I couldn't figure it out, I've been trying to solve **Number 7** for 5 hours now.

[image: Slash Puzzle]

Text transcription:

`/|////|| /|//|||| /|//|||/ /|///||| /|/|//|/ /|/////| /|/|/|// /|/|//||`

Comment: I've deleted the non-answer that so many have objected to while others have upvoted. I have no time for this. Here are the solutions to the riddles which were not part of the question: `1. N pnaqyr. 2. Gurer vf ab fgnvepnfr, vg'f n fvatyr-fgbel ubhfr. 3. N znc. 4. Va gur qvpgvbanel. 5. "vapbeerpgyl" 6. Gur guveq zna jnf onyq.`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It says

> CONGRATS

Reasoning

> Convert / to 0, | to 1 and then convert each binary block (byte) to their corresponding ASCII characters.